# Java Script: Using a Toggle to Show More or Less

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help. I have to write a javascript code that will toggle the a  element for show more or less. If I click on show more, it should show the more with a link for show less.

**Problem I am Having**

**1.** If I click show more About the Author, **instead of just showing more info about just that, it will also show more info about the book description, and who this book is for.**. I don't want it to do that, I just want it to show me more info about just that specific one.

**2.** It's also not showing me or giving me the **less** link option.

**Here is my HTML and JavaScript code.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#jdom").click(function() {
        $("a").toggle(function () {
            $(this).text("").siblings("div").hide();
        }, function() {
            $(this).text("Less").siblings("div").show();
        });
    });
    
});
```

```css
article, aside, figure, figcaption, footer, header, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
 width: 650px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 3px solid blue;
}
section {
 padding: 15px 25px;
}
h1 { 
 font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
}
div.hide {
 display: none;
}
ul {
 padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
 padding-bottom: .4em;
}
p, a {
 padding-bottom: .4em;
 padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Expand/Collapse</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="subset_expansion.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
 <section id="jdom">
  <h1>Murach's JavaScript and DOM Scripting</h1>
  <h2>Book description</h2>
  <div>
            <p>You can read other JavaScript books from start to finish and still not
            know how to develop dynamic websites like you want to.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            <p>But now, you can go from JavaScript beginner to DOM scripting expert in a 
      single book! Fast-paced, professional, and packed with expert practices, our 
   new JavaScript book.</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Show more</a>   
  
  <h2>About the author</h2>
  <div>
            <p>Ray Harris is an expert JavaScript programmer. That will be obvious to you 
            as soon as you review the 20 complete applications that he presents in this 
            book.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
   <p>Ray Harris is much more than a JavaScript programmer.</p>
   <p>So when Ray said he wanted to write for us, it didn't take us long to hire 
   him.</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Show more</a>
   
  <h2>Who this book is for</h2>
  <div>
            <p>Due to our unique presentation methods and this book's modular organization,
   this is the right book for any web developer who wants to use JavaScript effectively.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide"> 
   <p>Here's just a partial list of who can use this book:</p>
   <ul>
    <li>Web developers who know HTML and CSS and are ready to master JavaScript.</li> 
    <li>Web developers who program in ASP.NET, JSP, or PHP on the server side and 
    now want to master client-side coding.</li>
    <li>Web developers who have already read 3 or 4 JavaScript or DOM scripting books 
    but still don't know how to do the type of DOM scripting that's required in 
    real-world applications</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Show more</a>    
 
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you are binding click event to complete `jdom` section not specific to `show more` link. is that intentionally added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the HTML a bit, and JS as well. Try using like this, it might give you solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var moreSection = $(this).parents(".section").find(".more-section");
        if($(this).text() == "Show more" && moreSection.hasClass("hide")){
   $(this).text("Show less");
   moreSection.removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
  }else{
   $(this).text("Show more")
   moreSection.addClass("hide").removeClass("show");
  }
    });
 
});
```

```css
article, aside, figure, figcaption, footer, header, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
 width: 650px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 3px solid blue;
}
section {
 padding: 15px 25px;
}
h1 { 
 font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
}
div.hide {
 display: none;
}
div.show {
 display: block;
}
ul {
 padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
 padding-bottom: .4em;
}
p, a {
 padding-bottom: .4em;
 padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="jdom">
  <h1>Murach's JavaScript and DOM Scripting</h1>
  <h2>Book description</h2>
  <div class="section">
            <p>You can read other JavaScript books from start to finish and still not
            know how to develop dynamic websites like you want to.</p>
   <div class="hide more-section">
    <p>But now, you can go from JavaScript beginner to DOM scripting expert in a 
    single book! Fast-paced, professional, and packed with expert practices, our 
    new JavaScript book.</p>
   </div>
   <a href="#">Show more</a>
        </div>
  <h2>About the author</h2>
  <div class="section">
            <p>Ray Harris is an expert JavaScript programmer. That will be obvious to you 
            as soon as you review the 20 complete applications that he presents in this 
            book.</p>
   <div class="hide more-section">
    <p>Ray Harris is much more than a JavaScript programmer.</p>
    <p>So when Ray said he wanted to write for us, it didn't take us long to hire him.</p>
   </div>
   <a href="#">Show more</a>
        </div>
        
   
  <h2>Who this book is for</h2>
  <div class="section">
            <p>Due to our unique presentation methods and this book's modular organization,
   this is the right book for any web developer who wants to use JavaScript effectively.</p>
   <div class="hide more-section"> 
    <p>Here's just a partial list of who can use this book:</p>
    <ul>
     <li>Web developers who know HTML and CSS and are ready to master JavaScript.</li> 
     <li>Web developers who program in ASP.NET, JSP, or PHP on the server side and 
     now want to master client-side coding.</li>
     <li>Web developers who have already read 3 or 4 JavaScript or DOM scripting books 
     but still don't know how to do the type of DOM scripting that's required in 
     real-world applications</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <a href="#">Show more</a>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

***Try This,***

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('click','a',function(e){
         $(this).text( ($(this).text()  == "Show more") ? "Less":"Show more" ) ;
         $(document).find($(this).attr('data-target')).toggle();

         /*OR WITH ANIMATION*/
         /*
         if($(this).text()  == "Show more"){
            $(this).text("Less");
            $(document).find($(this).attr('data-target')).slideDown(300);
         }else{
            $(this).text("Show more");
            $(document).find($(this).attr('data-target')).slideUp(300);
         }*/
      });



    /*MORE ACTION*//*
     $(document).on('click','#jdom',function(e){
             $(document).find('a').each(function(){
                     $(this).trigger('click');
             })
          });
    */
    });
```

**HTML PART UPDATE AS BELOW**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Expand/Collapse</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="subset_expansion.js"></script>     
</head>

<body>
    <section id="jdom">
        <h1>Murach's JavaScript and DOM Scripting</h1>
        <h2>Book description</h2>
        <div>
            <p>You can read other JavaScript books from start to finish and still not
            know how to develop dynamic websites like you want to.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide" id="bookDesc">
            <p>But now, you can go from JavaScript beginner to DOM scripting expert in a 
            single book! Fast-paced, professional, and packed with expert practices, our 
            new JavaScript book.</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#" data-target="#bookDesc">Show more</a>           

        <h2>About the author</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Ray Harris is an expert JavaScript programmer. That will be obvious to you 
            as soon as you review the 20 complete applications that he presents in this 
            book.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide" id="author">
            <p>Ray Harris is much more than a JavaScript programmer.</p>
            <p>So when Ray said he wanted to write for us, it didn't take us long to hire 
            him.</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#" data-target="#author">Show more</a>

        <h2>Who this book is for</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Due to our unique presentation methods and this book's modular organization,
            this is the right book for any web developer who wants to use JavaScript effectively.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide" id="bookDet"> 
            <p>Here's just a partial list of who can use this book:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Web developers who know HTML and CSS and are ready to master JavaScript.</li> 
                <li>Web developers who program in ASP.NET, JSP, or PHP on the server side and 
                now want to master client-side coding.</li>
                <li>Web developers who have already read 3 or 4 JavaScript or DOM scripting books 
                but still don't know how to do the type of DOM scripting that's required in 
                real-world applications</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="#" data-target="#bookDet">Show more</a>                

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: let me update the full code properly and than downvote me